# Getting model attribute using javascript value as key

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I am generating a select option using JQuery within a thymeleaf template. The key for the options within the model map is the same as the `field.fieldName` javascript variable. Is there a way I can use this variable to get the option list from the model?

```
var $select = $("<select>", {"id": field.fieldName, "name": field.fieldName});
var options = [[${field.fieldName}]];
$.each(options, function(key, value) {
    $select.append($("<option></option>").attr(key).text(value));
})
```

Comment: Why does options contain just one value, which is an array, not a string?

Comment: I am trying to get options from the model. If the model key was known I would be using `var options = [[${modelKeyForList}]];`. However, in this case I trying to use the value in `field.fieldName` as the key to get the model attribute

Comment: What would this look like in regular JavaScript? Something like `model.options[field.fieldName]`? In that case, would you need to do something like `model.options[[[${field.fieldName}]]]`?

(Can you tell I have no idea how thymeleaf works? Just trying to help ;P)

Comment: The model is being sent from a Spring controller. Thyemleaf will then retrieve the attributes of the model using `${attributeName}`. It can also be usied in inline javascript byy adding the double square brackets: `[[$attributeName]]`. The model itself is not sent to the client. And I think I have just answered my own question. The thyemleaf generation happens server side, JQuery client side. As such, I'm guessing the javascript variable cannot actually be used by the server side thymeleaf template

Comment: Why use jquery/javascript for this can be done using simple `th:each` tag in the `select` element?

Comment: I am looking into annoation based form configuration. The form configuration is sent to the client in JSON form and then rendered client side from that configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Thyemeaf generation happens client side, while the javascript is exectuted client side. As such, the javascript variable will not have a value at this point and cannot be used by the Thymeleaf template